# Using gSOAP to consume a Web Service from C++

Tags: c++, soap-client, gsoap

I have followed this page to generate client proxy of Web Service: https://www.genivia.com/doc/soapdoc2.html#tth_sEc1.2

The problem is that what occurs is different from what the document says it should occur.

For instance, this file was generated by "wsdl2h -o WSLipigas.h http_of_wsdl": WSLipigas.h

On the other hand, these files were generated by "soapcpp2 -i -C -Iimport WSLipigas.h": ns1.nsmap, SoapC.cpp, soapH.h, soapStub.h.

soapcpp2 output is different from what documentation says, even when i am using version 2.8.

When I examined the generated files, I didn't find any class that I can use conveniently.

The only methods i found were of the type "soap_METHOD_VERB_send__ns1__ACTUALFUNCTION" and "soap_METHOD_VERB_send__ns1__ACTUALFUNCTIONResponse"

With that, i don't now how to proceed later on.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: soap_METHOD_VERB_send__ns1__ACTUALFUNCTION is the function to call if you want a C style experience.  For a C++ class look for a file ending in Proxy.h ( you don't mention it but it should have been generated if you use -I and don't use -c )

Comment: https://www.genivia.com/doc/soapdoc2.html#tth_sEc7.1.4 talks about the proxy classes

Comment: Can you be more specific in your question? I would expect WSLipigas.h to be generated by wsdl2h as you specified in the command. And soapcpp2 generates client proxy files, but only if the WSDL has SOAP/XML service operations in it. Perhaps try wsdl2h option -R for REST services in the WSDL as the wsdl2h help instructions show.

Comment: Hehe... this question is quite old  At this time, it is working at my customer's office. Thanks anyways.